# How to inject WCF client into ServiceCollection with passing endpoint and credentials as parameters?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Currently we are moving away from Castle Windsor container and I've been struggling to find examples of how to inject WCF client into service collection in .NET Core Startup.cs. Does anybody know how to do that with passing endpoint and credentials?

Here is how it was done for Castle Windsor container:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUserServiceV1>()
            .AsWcfClient(new DefaultClientModel
            {
                Endpoint = WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential) { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647, ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0), CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0), OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0), SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0) })
                        .At($"{userService.Url}/Services/UserService.svc")
            }
                .Credentials(new Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Behaviors.UserNameCredentials(userService.Username, userService.Password)))
            .LifestyleTransient());
```

I would like to do that using .NET Core Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code snippets, the WCF service on the server-side is created by BasichttpsBinding with TransportWithMessageCredential security mode and authenticates the client with username/password.
As far as I know, it is not compatible with the Asp.net Core project. Namely, it cannot be consumed properly in the Asp.net Core project. so it is not feasible.
[image]
Official repository.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/8
I would like to know more details about the service on the server-side.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We decided to leave Castle Windsor for WCF services injection for now. As for server-side details I'm afraid I don't have much more. We just utilize them using custom nuget packages

Comment: can you consume the service properly by the above DI in the Asp.net Core project?

Comment: Yes, I can. We just wanted to move from Castle Windsor. Looks like it's difficult and unnecessary

Comment: I am confused. in my opinion, this kind of service could not be called in the Asp.net Core project.  Have you tried to call it by using Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider(add service reference), please share the auto-generated configuration on the client-side with me.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The project is actually targeting net461